# Is EMM what I'm looking for?

Tags: java, android, push, android-for-work

We have a Java based web application and an android app for our enterprise needs. We would like to remotely push the android app from the web application and we don't know how to achieve this. After searching in Google, I found Android EMM but did not understand what that is exactly as there were no other blogs or tutorials other than the Google site which was difficult for me to understand.

It is similar to MDM solution but do MDM servers have an app preinstalled in the devices so that the installed app manages the installation of other apps?

Can anybody tell how to remotely push the android app from my web application?

Answer (score 0):

To remotely push an app to an Android device you need to manage this device, you cannot just push an app on anyone's device. To manage a device you need to set up this device as managed, which will require a factory reset.

If you want to pursue this approach you can try the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/).

Comment: Yes, few years back android devices could be managed only if there is a system app preinstalled in the devices whereas iOS devices don't need that preinstalled app(iOS device management could be done using profiles). I wanted to know if that is still the case with Android devices or has anything improved. Anyways will check out the link you shared.

Comment: You don't need a system app pre-installed to manage a device. You can use any device running Android 5.1 or above, you just need to set it up as managed after factory reset.

Comment: iOS is similar to Android on that aspect. iOS profiles don't allow installing app without consent, unless the device is in supervised mode which requires factory reset of the device and connecting it to a computer to enable supervised mode.

Comment: A profile can be installed to manage iOS devices which does not require a factory reset.

Comment: But a profile doesn't allow you to install apps silently unless it is in supervised mode. See [this article](https://simplemdm.com/2016/08/09/install-apps-silently/).

Comment: A .mobileconfig file can be downloaded from a server which will install the profile in the device. Thought the user has  to approve this, it does not require factory reset. The path to download can be conveyed to user by mail.

Comment: Are you trying to "remotely push" the app on the device, or just to install it? Because if you just want to install then yes sending the link or directly the app over email works on iOS and Android and doesn't require an EMM. But from your question it seems you wanted to remotely push.

Comment: I want to install the app on the device from my web application. I thought push and install were same terms.

Comment: To clarify: if you want to install an app without user consent on the device you need supervised mode on iOS or Device Owner on Android, both requiring factory reset. If you are ok with asking user consent then you don't need any config, you can just send the link to the app via email.

Comment: By sending a link you mean, the play store link? That wouldn't be helpful as I need to send additional information. If you are aware of iOS MDM Protocol, I'm looking for something similar in Android without using another app or factory reset.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can just upload .apk file to your server and provide a link to the user. This is a very simple solution but requires user to agree "install apk from third party sources". In this case, a user needs to agree with installing apk.

If you want to install apk without user agreement you need to activate Device Owner on Android (Fred mentioned in the comment this approach).